# Should I create use singleton to share data with every view or just pass data trough delegates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, singleton

My app has 5 sections initiating from `HomeViewController`, which is root of `navigationController`. Now each section pushes 5-10 views into the navigation stack, these views are making network connections as they go, and when coming back, the views are popped but I pass the data back to `HomeViewController` for performance purposes, so I don't need to repeat the network requests.

That said, I have two questions:

1. Do I need to create a `singleton` class, with a global shared instance, making sure the `init` process happens only once? Isn't my `HomeVC` doing the work, since I will always have it open, therefore maintaining `properties` alive?
2. Should I allow classes to get the `singleton` or `Home` properties and make changes? Or should I pass data trough delegates?

Delegates Example:

```
// HomeView.m
-(void)pushAnotherView
{
    view2.property = self.property;
}

View2.m
-(void)backButtonPressed
{
    // Pass property back to Home
}
```

Example2:

```
// Home.h
@property (nonAtomic, strong) NSString *propertyStr;

// View2.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) HomeViewController *homeVC;

// Home.m
-(void)pushAnotherView 
{ 
    view2.home = self; 
}

// View2.m

-(void)someMethod
{
    self.homeVC.propertyStr = @"Make changes here";
}
```

Comment: Would not recommend having `HomeVC` do the work- it is a "View Controller" and by nature should only be expected to control that view. If you're going to treat it like a singleton, why not just create an actual singleton so that the functionality is segregated to where it makes the most sense?

Comment: Thanks, as we are on the subject, can you please check my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205778/repeated-code-for-network-connections ? It's kind of the same thing, just trying to figure out the best design pattern to follow, I just didn't want to mix the questions and make it more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the data model and data-related concerns from your View Controller structure. Your model could be anything from Core Data to a singleton class with a bunch of properties. The model's only access should be via a Model Controller (which would probably be  singleton). The model controller would have separate methods for requesting all the data your app needs with block-driven callbacks.

When a View Controller needs data for its view, it contacts the Model Controller and requests it. The Model Controller would check the Model to see if the requested data is available. If it is, the Model Controller immediately invokes the completion block with the requested data. If not, it retrieves the requested data from a network API. Upon successful download and parsing of the data, it is stored into the model for future use and THEN the completion block is invoked with the data.

With this pattern, the View Controllers don't need to know how to retrieve data and don't need to manage its state, all that logic is shifted to the Model Controller.

Example completion block:

```
typedef void (^ListDataCompletionBlock)(BOOL success, NSArray *listData);
```

Then the model controller would have a method like:

```
- (void)requestListDataWithCompletion:(ListDataCompletionBlock)completion;
```

The call from the View Controller would look like:

```
[[MyModelController sharedInstance] requestListDataWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSArray *listData) {
    if (success) {
        // Use the listData.
    } else {
        // Recover from being unable to retrieve the requested data.
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, thanks, that makes sense. But the thing is, I use parse.com as backend for my app and they have some practical features like the `PFQueryTableViewController`, which makes the connection to the server in the `view` and populates it. It also takes care of caching the data. Which works great for me. But for example, on this view, I have methods to organize the data the way I want and populate the view, but I will also need the organized data on other views, but not necessarily to display the same results, tables.

Comment: That's why I'm thinking about storing the data in the singleton, but not really make the server requests on it. What do you think?

Comment: Ahh... well, in that case, a singleton data storage object is probably the most straight-forward solution. I don't advocate delegates as a means of passing data around the app except something simple like a user selection... they're hard to follow and can cause an app to crash if you forget to implement a delegate method then invoke it.